# node.js: Understanding object prototype

Tags: javascript, node.js

There may be several duplicate to this question based on the title of question, but I have a very specific scenario.

I am building a node module sample code below

```
var myModule = function() {
  // do something init
};

myModule.prototype.a = 10;
myModule.prototype.b = 20;

myModule.prototype.method1 = function() {
  // in this method I can access a and b using this
  this.a
  this.b
};

myModule.prototype.method2 = function() {
  // I can call method1 here
  this.method1();
};
```

This will works fine for below case mentioned

```
var myModule = require('myModule');
var instance = new myModule();
```

calling method2 on instance will work fine

```
instance.method2 // this should work fine
```

Now suppose I am passing method2 as a callback function to express or any other function like below

```
someobject.performsomeasync(instance.method2); // this will fail
```

As far as I understood about JavaScript prototype is that the above will fail because in that case `this` will refer to caller object which is not `instance`

How to make it work ?
And what I am doing is considered a good coding practise ?

Answer (score 1):

You can provide `this` through the [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method:

```js
someobject.performsomeasync(instance.method2.bind(instance));
```

Another solution:

```js
someobject.performsomeasync(function() {
    instance.method2();
});
```

**UPD1**

Following our discussion, you want that methods of your object always 
will be executed in context of object instance. Then you can do:

```js
var myModule = function() {
     this.method1 = method1.bind(this);
     this.method2 = method2.bind(this);
};

myModule.prototype.a = 10;
myModule.prototype.b = 20;

function method1() {
    // in this method I can access a and b using this
    this.a
    this.b
};

function method2() {
    // I can call method1 here
    this.method1();
};
```

But this is very bad style. Users of your library are javascript developers. So they must know if you passes callback like `someobject.performsomeasync(instance.method2)` you just passes method of the object, not context. So they must use `bind` to provide context.

**PS** By the way I recommend you not to defined properties of object in your prototype. Define just methods (maybe also constants). It's very error prone. For example if your property is object, then someone can write next code:

```js
instance.someobject.a = 10;
```

and he'll change `a` for `someobject` property for all instances.

Comment: As I am building a npm module I don't have control over the usage

Comment: @Syed Actually, I do not fully understand your problem? What do you mean "don't have control over the usage"? You are writing module, so you are creating interface (that you'll describe in documentation) that users of your module will use. Can you explain more what is confusing your?

Comment: As I already mentioned I don't have control over the code which you are proposing as solution. It is npm module and users can call the function in whatever way they want.

Comment: @Syed Users must know that function must be called in context of `instance` object. So they will use `.bind()` to do it.

Comment: Yes I will document that in documentation but do you believe that the docs will say that if you have to pass a function of my module to a callback you cannot directly pass like `someobject.performsomeasync(instance.method2)` you have to pass like `someobject.performsomeasync(function() {
    instance.method2();
});`

Comment: @Syed They must know it. It's base of javascript.

Comment: Users may or may not use bind I can't be sure but I have to design my module in a robust way. That is why I asked whether what I am doing is in correct way or not. Feel free to correct me. I just started writing the code

Comment: @Syed update the answer. This is robust way. But I please you not to do it.